# How to trigger any matplotlib navigation button from external function?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

Can one trigger any of these matplotlib navigation button from an external function, such as a pyqt button?

[image]

Comment: Could you explain yourself better, do you want to invoke the slots associated with those buttons? or do you want to emulate the click on those buttons?

Comment: @eyllanesc Yeah right, I would like to invoke/call the function of the matplotlib button with an own function or an custom created pyqt button.